# SQL - Including groups with most recent ownership

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

My dataset includes tests on owned devices, but a device can be bought and resold, and we only want the tests associated with the most recent ownership.

The data set looks like this:

```
TestID               ProductID       RegistrationID     TestDate
00021357916020      P3K25EL141297        89D617         2019-07-22
00021357915928      P3K25EL141297        89D617         2019-07-15
00021353422334      P3K25EL141297        5PKY90         2019-05-31
```

I need to refine to only include the tests for Registration 89D617, as those are the tests with the most recent ownership. We're not provided with any reference information for the ownership change, and the registration IDs do not increase in a meaningful order so I've haven't been able to figure a means of grouping these.

To clarify - the table would need to include both entries with RegistrationID of 89D617 as those are all tests with the most recent registration.

Comment: You may be able to use a SQL trigger to save the latest edit to that table.  Though, that depends whether other entries will be added/edited after it's in production.  Is there a table that keeps all RegistrationIDs?  Those don't appear to be unique in your example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT t.TestID, t.ProductID, t.RegistrationID, t.TestDate
FROM (
  SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(RegistrationID) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY TestDate DESC) reg
  FROM tablename  
) t
WHERE t.RegistrationID = t.reg
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95db06f94bea73292cfc8343921640bf).
Results:

```
> TestID      | ProductID     | RegistrationID | TestDate               
> :---------- | :------------ | :------------- | :---------
> 21357916020 | P3K25EL141297 | 89D617         | 2019-07-22
> 21357915928 | P3K25EL141297 | 89D617         | 2019-07-15
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the rows whose `RegistrationID` has the latest `TestDate` per `ProductID`. If so, a simple option is to filter with a correlated subquery;

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.RegistrationID = (
    select top (1) RegistrationID  
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.ProductID = t.ProductID
    order by TestDate desc
)
```

This query would take advante of an index on `(RegistrationID, testDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(TestID NVARCHAR(50), 
                 ProductID NVARCHAR(50), 
                 RegistrationID NVARCHAR(50), 
                 TestDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    ('00021357916020','P3K25EL141297','89D617','2019-07-22'),
    ('00021357915928','P3K25EL141297','89D617','2019-07-15'),
    ('00021353422334','P3K25EL141297','5PKY90','2019-05-31');

-- Or like this...

SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    @t t1
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 RegistrationID 
     FROM @t 
     WHERE ProductID = t1.ProductID 
     ORDER BY TestDate DESC) t2
WHERE
    t2.RegistrationID = t1.RegistrationID;
```